# Detect whether the application was launched by a mouse click?

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, winforms, mouse

Is it possibly to detect if an application was started by a click or double click? (notice that the user can set an option in windows mouse config control panel to open files only with one left click instead two clicks).

I would like to restrict the execution of an application if it is launched by clicking on it, but I don't know how to detect that so by now I'm evaluating a random argument like this:

```
Private Shadows Sub Startup() Handles MyBase.Startup

    Dim Arg As String = My.Application.CommandLineArgs.FirstOrDefault

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Arg) _
    OrElse Not Arg.Equals("ForceRun", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then

        End

    End If

End Sub
```

So with the modification that I want the pseudo code should be something like this:

```
Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    Private Shadows Sub Startup() Handles MyBase.Startup

        If AppIsLaunchedFromMouse Then End

    End Sub

    Private Function AppIsLaunchedFromMouse() As Boolean
        Return...
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: My theory is, it won't be easy if at all possible, as the double/single-click event is interpreted by the windows shell at that point. The shell in turn will lookup what it is programmed to do on a click, then lookup the file-type in the registry and execute it appropriatly. You can define default arguments for filetypes in your registry (or with assoc/ftype) or you can create links, that have default arguments. But afaik the shell does not inform the program it's executing whether it was prompted to do so by a mouse single/double-click or a keyboard event for that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with MrPaulch that it won't be easy. If you want to distinguish between the user launching the program and e.g. you launching the program from another program you could use a special command line parameter that only you know. If the program is not started with this parameter it means it was done by other means than the ones you handle yourself.
I don't know if that is what you want, though.